# Weird Error for using ? Operator

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The type of the conditional expression can not be determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424231/the-type-of-the-conditional-expression-can-not-be-determined)

I currently wrote this statement:

```
byte? Col_8 = (Rad_8.SelectedValue == null) ? null : byte.Parse(Rad_8.SelectedValue);
```

but it has this Error:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between `'<null>'` and `'byte'`

why I can use null after `?` ? what if equivalent of above code without `if` statement?

Comment: what is Rad_8.SelectedValue type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler cannot infer the type of the conditional statement because `null` has no type and it does not consider the expected return value.
Use

```
(Rad_8.SelectedValue == null) ? (byte?)null : byte.Parse(Rad_8.SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Rad_8.SelectedValue == null)
    Col_8 = null;
else 
    Col_8 = byte.Parse(Rad_8.SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because the method `byte.Parse(...)` does not return a nullable type, therefore the compiler is saying there is not implicit conversion between the `null`- and `byte`-types. Try casting the `null` value with `(byte?)` to explicitly specify it's type.